# Hyperparameter tuning Random Forest Classifier with GridSearchCV based on probability

Tags: python, random-forest, hyperparameters

Just starting in on hyperparameter tuning for a Random Forest binary classification, and I was wondering if anyone knew/could advise on how to set the scoring to be based off predicted probabilities rather than the predicted classification. Ideally I'd want something that would consider for roc_auc in the below the probabilities (i.e. **[0.2,0.6,0.7,0.1,0.0]**) rather than classifications (i.e. **[0,1,1,0,0]**).

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier as rfc
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV

rfbase = rfc(n_jobs = 3, max_features = 'auto', n_estimators = 100, bootstrap=False)

param_grid = {
    'n_estimators': [200,500],
    'max_features': [.5,.7],
    'bootstrap': [False, True],
    'max_depth':[3,6]
}

rf_fit = GridSearchCV(estimator=rfbase, param_grid=param_grid
      , scoring = 'roc_auc')
```

I figure currently the roc_auc is going off the actual classifications . Wanted to check if there was a more efficient way before I charged off into creating a custom scoring function, thanks in advance for the help here!

Comment: Check out skearn's [make_scorer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html). It has a `needs_proba` param. You might be able to shimmy something together from [this example](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/3227)?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, just what I'm looking for! If you want to move this to an answer I'll happily vote it once I test it :)

Comment: Confirmed working as expecting, thanks again for the quick help here!

Comment: Just glad it helped. It's up to you but you might want to answer your own question with your solution that you found to work. According to SO, it's [encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) despite some grumblings from certain "experts" that dislike and dismiss this fact.

Comment: I am getting "IndexError: too many indices for array" error in the line return roc_auc_score( y_true, y_pred[:,1])

Comment: @Jarad and Ben , Can you guys help me out here ?

Comment: Hey @Mighty, I think you're probably getting this because your y_pred is just an array of floats (i.e. predicted probabilities). In my example it was an array of tuples of class likelihoods (classes [0,1]) since I was using random forest classifier (i.e. [.7, .3], [.45, .55]). If your y_pred is just an array you can drop the "[:, 1]" component of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Final solve using the reference Jarad provided:

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier as rfc
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV

rfbase = rfc(n_jobs = 3, max_features = 'auto', n_estimators = 100, bootstrap=False)

param_grid = {
    'n_estimators': [200,500],
    'max_features': [.5,.7],
    'bootstrap': [False, True],
    'max_depth':[3,6]
}

def roc_auc_scorer(y_true, y_pred):
    return roc_auc_score(y_true, y_pred[:, 1])
scorer = make_scorer(roc_auc_scorer, needs_proba=True)

rf_fit = GridSearchCV(estimator=rfbase, param_grid=param_grid
      , scoring = scorer)
```